# LEFT JOIN using PDO comparing same table with itself

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning PDO and have been converting my normal mysql code to PDO code. I am stuck on a LEFT join bit of code. I get an error saying that I have an unexpected 'S1' (T-String) ...........refers to my SELECT line

The code is as follows

```
$cif_stp_indicator=Null;
$cif_train_uid="Y63553";
$schedule_start_date="2015-01-24";
$schedule_end_date="2015-01-24";

$movedata=$mysql_link->prepare(SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
FROM schedule s1
LEFT JOIN schedule s2
ON (s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator=:s2.cif_stp_indicator AND s1.cif_train_uid=:s1.cif_train_uid AND s1.schedule_start_date<=:s1.schedule_start_date AND s1.schedule_end_date>=:s1.schedule_end_date);

$movedata->execute(array(':s2.cif_stp_indicator'=>$cif_stp_indicator,':s1.cif_train_uid'=>$cif_train_uid,':s1.schedule_start_date'=>$schedule_start_date,':schedule_end_date'=>$schedule_end_date)); 

foreach($movedata->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
 echo $row['cif_train_uid'];    
 echo $row['cif_stp_indicator'];
}
```

Please can you help as to what the problem is.

EDIT - THIS IS THE MYSQL VERSION I HAVE TRIED TO REPRESENT AS PDO. THIS WORKS AS MYSQL

```
$cif_stp_indicator=null;
$cif_train_uid='Y63553';
$schedule_start_date='2015-01-24';
$schedule_end_date='2015-01-24';

$b="SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
FROM schedule s1
LEFT JOIN schedule s2
ON (s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator is NULL AND s1.cif_train_uid='$cif_train_uid' AND s1.schedule_start_date<='$schedule_start_date' AND s1.schedule_end_date>='$schedule_end_date'";

$l=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$b);    

if ($l) {

 while($berths=mysqli_fetch_array($l,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  { 

   echo $berths['cif_train_uid'];   
   echo $berths['cif_stp_indicator'];

  }   
}
```

FINAL WORKING ANSWER

```
$cif_train_uid='Y63553';
$schedule_start_date='2015-01-24';
$schedule_end_date='2015-01-24';

$sql="SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
FROM schedule s1
LEFT JOIN schedule s2
ON (s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator is NULL AND s1.schedule_start_date=:s1_schedule_start_date AND s1.schedule_end_date=:s1_schedule_end_date";  

$movedata=$mysql_link->prepare($sql); 

$movedata->bindValue(':s1_schedule_start_date',$schedule_start_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$movedata->bindValue(':s1_schedule_end_date',$schedule_end_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$movedata->execute();

$array=$movedata->fetchAll();
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++){
echo $array[$i]['cif_train_uid'];
echo $array[$i]['cif_stp_indicator'];
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Just getting 'syntax error, unexpected 's1' (T_STRING) in.........However I felt I need the s1 as I used it in the traditional mysql code.......

Comment: Until the syntax error is handled, nothing will work.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to quote the sql string, and also your loop is wrong, try this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator,s1.schedule_start_date
FROM schedule s1
LEFT JOIN schedule s2 ON 
(s1.cif_train_uid=s2.cif_train_uid AND 
 s1.cif_stp_indicator>s2.cif_stp_indicator)
WHERE s2.cif_stp_indicator=:s2_cif_stp_indicator AND 
      s1.cif_train_uid=:s1_cif_train_uid AND 
      s1.schedule_start_date<=:s1_schedule_start_date AND
      s1.schedule_end_date>=:s1_schedule_end_date
";

$movedata=$mysql_link->prepare($sql);

$movedata->execute(array(':s2_cif_stp_indicator'=>$cif_stp_indicator,
                         ':s1_cif_train_uid'=>$cif_train_uid,
                         ':s1_schedule_start_date'=>$schedule_start_date,
                         ':s1_schedule_end_date'=>$schedule_end_date
           )); 

while($row = $movedata->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo $row['cif_train_uid'];    
     echo $row['cif_stp_indicator'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Meda. I am getting a new error now which I am working through. It says 'Uncaught Exception (PDOException) with message SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error on access violation : 1064.......check..........for the right syntax to use near '.cif_stp_indicator AND s1_cif_train_uid=?.cif_train_uid AND cif_schedule_start_da' at line 5

Comment: please remove the dots from your placeholders I dont advise that

Comment: Do you mean s1 schedule_start_date instead of s1.schedule_start_date? When you say you don't advise that do you mean do not put the 'dots' in?

Comment: Thanks Meda - the code is now running without error. Its just not picking up cif_train_uid="Y63553" for some reason. Just checking it out

Comment: Just did a var_dump($movedata); and got (PDOStatement) #5 (1) { ["querystring"]=> string(406) "SELECT s1.cif_train_uid,s1.cif_stp_indicator.............etc - ie all the script that sits within the $sql quotes ..is that right?

Comment: Try to echo out the query and run directly to mysql

Comment: Thanks Meda for your help - going to try again in the morning using my old mysql code (ie not PDO)

Comment: @user2635961 what do you mean by `Its just not picking up cif_train_uid="Y63553"`?

Comment: The Y63553 is just some example data to test if the code is working. I have now shown (at top under EDIT) the original MYSQL code (ie the code I was trying to change into PDO). The original MYSQL code worked.ie found the set of data where $cif_train_uid="Y63553". Could it be related to the 'is Null' command which I show as a string in PDO ?

Comment: I am struggling to echo ($movedata); - just get object of class PDOstatement could not be converted to a string

Comment: Still struggling bro? You need to var_dump its an object not a string!!

Comment: It turns out I was not assigning the NULL value correctly. (I realise I had not highlighted the NULL value part very clearly in my question). Updated final answer given in the top question part. Many thanks for your help. I cannot seem to be able to edit your answer to give a tick. Have given a vote up instead